# 他の人の firebase 環境にプロジェクトを作ってあげる方法はありますか？

Tags: firebase

相手アカウント下の firebase に、私がリモートでプロジェクトを新規作成する方法はありますか？

例えば、
相手から私に何らかの権限を与えてもらえば、私は相手環境下の firebase でプロジェクトを新規作成できるようになり、作成後はその権限を外してもらうような。

---

複数人で firebase database の扱いを練習しています。

他の人との共有プロジェクトを作る際、私から相手所有の firebase 環境にプロジェクトを作ってあげることはできるのでしょうか？

例えば、

1. こちらでプロジェクトの雛形を作って、それを取り込んでもらう？
2. 相手の firebase にプロジェクトを遠隔で新規生成する？

など考えましたが、そもそも上記のことはできるのでしょうか？

私の firebase 環境下でプロジェクトを作成して相手と共有する方法だと、私の firebase 環境がプロジェクトだらけになり、無料枠 (10 projects?) を超えそうなので。

Comment: 正攻法で行くなら自分でプロジェクトを作って対象の人をプロジェクトに管理者として招待するのが良いと思います。プロジェクトの作成上限は申請すれば引き上げてもらえます。申請は[クラウドコンソール](https://console.developers.google.com/project)からプロジェクトを作成しようとした時上限に達していれば案内が出ると思うのでそこから申請してみてください。新しく作成できたらFirebaseコンソールからGCPプロジェクトをインポートすれば無料に切り替えられます。

Comment: # 返信遅くなってすいません、コメント付いてるの気付きませんでした

そうですね、試してみます。アドバイス、ありがとうございます。

Answer (score 1):

Firebaseに限りませんが同様に遠隔地の相手の環境をセットアップする場合、自分であれば[Chrome リモート デスクトップ](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/chrome-remote-desktop/gbchcmhmhahfdphkhkmpfmihenigjmpp?hl=ja)を利用して、直接相手のマシンを操作します。

Firebase側から見れば、相手の方が自分でセットアップするのと違いがないのでシンプルでオススメです。今回の場合相手の環境をセットアップした上で質問者さんに権限を共有するのも良いかもしれませんね。

ペアプロのようなことまでしたいのであれば、[Screenhero | Screen sharing for collaboration in teams](https://screenhero.com/)も良いです。

Comment: 情報ありがとうございます。

「Chrome リモート デスクトップ」って聞いたことありましたが使ったことありませんでした。早速試してみます。